# How to set relative path in ant script with spacing?

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant

I tried running the script ant:

```
<project name="build-Fusion" default="install-all" basedir="..">
    <property environment="env"/>

    <condition property="mvn.exec" value="mvn.bat" else="mvn">
        <os family="windows"/>
    </condition>

    <!-- colocar o value vazio para executar os junits -->
    <property name="skip.test" value="-Dmaven.test.skip=true"/>

    <target name="install-all">
        <echo>base dir=${basedir}</echo>
        <exec executable="${mvn.exec}" failonerror="true" dir="./">
            <arg value="install"/>
            <arg value="${skip.test}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

But i get this error:

> Buildfile: /Volumes/Ficheiro/Ambiente Desenvolvimento/Workspace
>   fusion/fusion/ant/build.xml install-all:
>        [echo] base dir=/Volumes/Ficheiro/Temp
>
> BUILD FAILED /Volumes/Ficheiro/Ambiente Desenvolvimento/Workspace
>   fusion/fusion/ant/build.xml:15: Execute failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "/Volumes/Ficheiro/Temp"):
>   error=2, No such file or directory
>
> Total time: 374 milliseconds

How to set **relative path** in ant script with spacing?

Comment: Is the `mvn` executable on the `PATH`? If not, you have to provide the absolute path to `mvn` in the `executable` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake . I do not set the variable Ant in IOS . After changing works for me!